# Click in one element, empty this and another

Tags: jquery

I'd like to empty the element user clicked and the other one by id.

So I tried:

```
<span class='approve_member' id='a_1' data-user='1' data-community='2'>Approve</span>

        <span class='remove_member' id='r_1' data-user='1' data-community='2'>Remove</span>
```

and jquery

```
$( document ).on( "click", ".approve_member", function(e) {

var element = $(this);

var us = element.attr("data-user");

        element.empty();
        ('#r_'+us).empty();


})
```

when click in approve it should also remove the remove link.

the `('#r_'+us).empty();` is not working to remove element remove_member. any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/g26h8q3p/5/

Answer (score 1):

You are just missing the `$` in the jQuery query selector:

```
$( document ).on( "click", ".approve_member", function(e) {
    var element = $(this);
    var us = element.attr("data-user");
    element.empty();
    $('#r_'+us).empty(); // You are missing the $ at the beginning of this line
});
```

Comment: You should just vote to close as a typo, it's not worth posting a full answer to questions like this.

Comment: @Barmar gotcha! I’ll take that into court.